# CSS - get rid of initially setup lists nav

Tags: html, css, href

I applied  CSS  in my Home page and as a header on all other pages, where the nav bar is lists  `<LI>… <UL>`. However, I can no longer get rid of the `<a href>` together with the 'mouseover hover'.  I can no longer use a simple HTML href link (not `<ul ...li>`!), independently of the initial set up.  I automatically get the same color, shape, mouse over as in the original set up in my home page (CSS). This is particularly annoying when I try to link a big image to my smaller sample images (thumb nails) of my paintings.

I have been trying to find the answer over the internet. I can see in many forums that I am not the only one; it appears that it is a occurring problem. But the suggestions supplied do not work (or I do not understand how to apply them).
 I am new to CSS. I learned some HTML years ago.

```
<style>

ul

{

float:top;center;

width:100%;

padding:0;

margin:0;

list-style-type:none;

}

a

{

float:left;

width:9em;

text-decoration:none;

color:Azure;

background-color:#000033;

padding:0.3em 0.7em;

border-right:1px solid white;

}

a:hover {background-color:#D4AF37;}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<ul>


</ul>

</td>

</tr>

<tr>

 <td>

<style>

ul

{

float:top;right;

width:100%;

padding:0;

margin:0;

list-style-type:none;

}

a

{

float:left;

width:9em;

text-decoration:none;

color:Azure;

background-color:#470647;

padding:0.3em 0.7em;

border-right:1px solid white;

}

a:hover {background-color:#D4AF37;}

</style>

</head>

<body>

<ul>


</ul>

</td>

</tr>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, I am a little unsure of what your question is. Could you isolate the problem in a http://jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 1):

Hi that happens when you define a style like this for the tags like `ul` `li` or `a`

```
a {
 color:blue;
}
```

That style applies for all the a tags in the HTML document, so to avoid this issue you can do more specific your CSS styles. Give to your `ul` menu a class name like `<ul class="navbar">` and then you can reffer to his specific `a` tags inside with this:

```
.navbar a{
  color:blue;
}
```

You can search more about CSS references like this article here

**http://css-tricks.com/little-css-stuff-newcomers-get-confused-about/**

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unclear as to what you're asking, plus the code provided is invalid in multiple places - that being said, i've supplied something i just made that will hopefully give you an idea of tables and lists because from what I see now - I can say that the css isn't valid - the html isn't valid.

```
    <html>
<head>
<style ="text/css">
tr, td {
    border: solid 1px red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <p> this is an ul with multiple levels</p>
                            <ul>
                                <li>list item level 1 - item 1 - product 1</li>
                                <li>list item level 1 - item 1 - product 2</li>
                                <li>list item level 1 - item 1 - product 3</li>
                                <li>list item level 1 - item 1 - product 3
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>list item level 2 product 1</li>
                                        <li>list item level 2 product 2</li>
                                        <li>list item level 2 product 3</li>
                                        <li>list item level 2 product 4
                                            <ul>
                                                <li> list item level 3 product 1</li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                <li>list item level 1 - item 2 - product 1</li>
                                <li>list item level 1 - item 3 - product 1</li>
                                <li>list item level 1 - item 4 - product 1</li>
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                    <td>
                <p> this is a table</p>
            <table>
                <tr colspan=2" >
                    <td>row 1</td>
                    <td>row 1</td>
                    <td>row 1</td>
                    <td>row 1</td>
                    <td>row 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>row 2</td>
                    <td>row 2</td>
                    <td>row 2</td>
                    <td>row 2</td>
                    <td rowspan="2">row 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>row 3</td>
                    <td>row 3</td>
                    <td colspan="2">row 3</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <p> if you notice rowspan is the equiv of going to the left or right and Colspan is the equiv of going up or down.  That's about as basic as a table gets</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I intentionally put everything surrounded in tables just to illustrate what you can do, should you need to nest multiple tables inside eachother.